# Are there different endings for Antichamber?

Tags: antichamber

I beat the game, but the timer ran out and I did not find all the pictures.  If you beat the game within the time limit, is there anything special that happens?  What about if you find all the pictures?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, there is only one ending.

Comment: For those interested, [here's a video of Antichamber's ending](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6jGKLxIrjs)

Answer (score 8):

The timer is explicitly there to demonstrate how pointless it is. Much of the game is about breaking gaming conventions.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one intended ending.

However, if you like seeing another, likely unintended ending, try to perform the last action in the game while jumping backwards out of the sphere. If you succeed, you then can watch the ending unfold from the outside, and keep roaming around the final map until the screen fades and the credits come on.